# bazel - JUnit4Runner inside bazel could be use with junit `Category`?

Tags: bazel-java

Bazel has their [JUnit4Runner](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:src/java_tools/junitrunner/java/com/google/testing/junit/runner/junit4/JUnit4Runner.java;l=46?q=JUnit4Runner&sq=&ss=bazel) in com.google.testing.junit package which seems to be based on junit4.

I tried to use Bazel JUnit4Runner with `Categroy` Annotation. But not worked for me.

And [1](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:src/java_tools/junitrunner/java/com/google/testing/junit/runner/junit4/JUnit4Runner.java;l=46?q=JUnit4Runner&sq=&ss=bazel) seems to support `testIncludeFilterRegexp` but not junit's `Categroy`.

So does JUnit4Runner from Bazel not support `Category`?
I am not sure. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When structuring `TestSuite` with Category, I had to use `@RunWith(Categories::class)`

Following code worked for me.

```
@RunWith(Categories::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(AllTests::class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(EnormousTest::class)
class AllEnormousTests

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite::class)
class AllTests
```